# object does not contain definition for pageNumber

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to simply run a `foreach` loop inside my view of my MVC application. But, in debug mode I can see it got the list successfully. However, I get an error saying object does not contain definition for pageNumber. Please, note pageNumber is available on each of those list. What am I doing wrong?

MVC View code:

```
@foreach (var button in ViewBag.PageButtons)
    {
        <li class="page-item"><a class="page-link" href="#">@button.pageNumber</a></li>
    }
```

[image: Debug Picture]

[image: Error picture]

Comment: You need to cast the value of `ViewBag` to your type (just another reason why you always pass a model to the view and never use `VIewBag`)

Comment: https://ibb.co/dhCbjx see here. pageNumber is available and contains number

Comment: Did you not read my previous comment? `ViewBag` is dynamic - you need to cast it

Comment: Can you plz tell me what change needed on ViewBag. I do not understand what you mean by cast

Comment: `@foreach (var button in (IEnumerable<Button>)ViewBag.PageButtons)` But DO NOT use `ViewBag`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error dialog and the message show the type of `button` is an `object` in the View. As the error states, the .NET `object` does not contain a definition of `pageNumber` indeed. In the View, you need to cast `button` to your type.

The new code may look like this (CRLFs are for readability):

```
@foreach (var button in ViewBag.PageButtons)
{
    <li class="page-item">
        <a class="page-link" href="#">
            @(((YourClassNameHere)button).pageNumber)
        </a>
    </li>
}
```

You need to replace `YourClassNameHere` with whatever class name you used to define an element of the list you send to the View.

Answer (score 0):

ViewBag is **dynamic**, so you'll need to cast your `button` for the call to `.pageNumber` to work:

```
@((button as PageButton).pageNumber)
```

or

```
@(((PageButton)button).pageNumber)
```